# ruby on rails receive parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am looking to receive parameters on Haml pages. I have been successful  to pass parameters on the link like

https://quickrent-akki4141-1.c9users.io/user_history?name=Akshay

Now I want the name "Akshay" in a variable.

Can somebody help me with that.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

CAREFUL! While the existing answers would technically work, they all are a huge security risk. If you just straight up display the query string parameter on your page you open up the site to all kinds of cross site scripting attacks including but not limited to

1. Stealing Cookies (and therefore possible user sessions)
2. Arbitrary evil javascript running on your page
3. Using javascript to manipulate the DOM

http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/

At the very least you need to sanitize the input of javascript, html, etc. To be completely safe you have to follow all these rules
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

I think you really need to evaluate WHY your doing this. Just based off your url, it looks like maybe you are taking the user input, doing an active record search based off the user name, then on the page displaying the user name and the history of this user? If thats the case then most likely the active record model data your getting back will contain this user name as well. If so you can use this in your view.

Comment: I don't think there is a security risk. No script is being stored by a user and executed by a another user. As a user (the user running this and "injecting code into the page") you can always do it from the browser developer tools, all three: read the cookies, run JS on the page, manipulate the DOM.

Comment: I could give you a link to my user history page, but actually put javascript in the query string param and disguise the link so you don't see its going to do bad things. Then I get all your cookies.
If i'm able to save my username as something malicious somehow, then whatever button generates this link would automatically be malicious. This is text book cross site scripting

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see it that way, but you are right, I wouldn't call it text-book, but yeah, certainly possible. ERB, HAML and SLIM all seem to escape by default, so this shouldn't be an issue anyways.

Comment: Awesome. Seems that as long as you are just displaying it on the page as text (not placing in links or using active record searches where you use actual sql which could lead to sql injection) rails 3.0 and higher handle this.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Ruby_on_Rails_Cheatsheet#Cross-site_Scripting_.28XSS.29
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss

Comment: That first link is gold! Thanks again for the resources and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

`params[:name]` will have the value you want. But you should reconsider "processing" that value on the view. Usually param handling is done on the controller, since is part of the request.

```
<%= params[:name] %>
```

Comment: What do you think about my `session` approach ? Good for passing data around right?

Comment: It depends where you want to pass data, in this case is not necessary to persist the data across requests.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way would be to create a helper that will handle that:

```
module ParamsHelper
  def name
    sanitize(params[:name])
  end
end
```

Then in a view

```
ParamsHelper.name
```

Or you can 'include' helper in controller by

```
helper ParamsHelper
```

and just use = name in the view

Comment: `params` is accessible on the view,  there is no need to assign it to a instance variable.

Comment: @Leito right, thanks! Came with better solution, I think

Answer (score 0):

To capture the parameter you are passing to the URL you should declare a method in you `application_controller.rb` file like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


            def capture_name
              session[:name] = params[:name] if params[:name]
              # then do whatever you want like assigning it to a variable if      that's what you are trying to acheive
            end
 end
```

Comment: After this how can i display the value on a haml page?

Comment: assign it to a variable like `@name = session[:name]` and use the `@name` variable in your view.

Comment: Why use the session? `params` is already accessible on the view.

Comment: so It can be accessed in other controller actions outside of `ApplicationController` I think this approach is more flexible.

Comment: I mean I cant figure out where I have to give this value to @name in the controller or in haml page?

Comment: Could you show us the controller action that is in charge of rendering the page you where you want to display the name parameter?

Comment: <%= link_to 'History' , user_history_path(:name => @user.name) %> I am sending the information like this from one page

Comment: But the param is set only on that request, why should it live outside of it? Storing it on the session it will keep the value across requests within the same session.